# How many different words can be formed from the word FACETIOUS (taking all letters), leaving the vowels in order A,E,I,O,U?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I thought of fixing _A_E_I_O_U_ first, and then remaining $6$ places can be occupied by F,C,T,S in several orders:
Case $1$: {F,C,T,S} as a group of $4$ can occupy in $C(6,1)$ and then permute them = $6*4!$
 Case $2$: Group of $3$ like {F,C,T} in $6$ places and then {S} in remaining $5$ places = $C(4,3)*6*3!*C(1,1)*5$
 Case $3$: Group of Two Two , which means $P(4,2)=12$ different set of $2$ elements each. From them , $C(12,1)*6*C(11,1)*5$...!! 
Iam confused about this case $3$. And also the rest of the problem.
Case $4$: One-One element can be placed in $6$ locations=$P(6,4)$

Comment: It's not really clear whether all vowels _have_ to be in each of the words, or if the requirement just is that those that do appear must be in order.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: My take on this is that all nine letters must be used.

Comment: @TonyK: That would be the easy case, of course.

Comment: All letters are to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that all nine letters have to be used, although your question is not entirely clear on this point.

First step: Choose the positions of the vowels: you are choosing $5$ positions out of $9$, so this is $\binom{9}{5}$.

Second step: Choose the order of the consonants in the remaining $4$ positions. This is just $4!$

Third step: Multiply these two numbers together.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in the question how many words can be formed of the words FACETIOUS ? with the condition

Comment: :Thanks. I dont know where my mind was wandering while solving this, that I made it so complicated.

Comment: @user2016963: The question is what "formed of" means. For example one could argue that CAT is possibly a word "formed of" FACETIOUS.

Comment: My mistake. Will take care of such ambiguity from here on. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here are three alternatives to Brian M. Scott's approach: (All give the same result, of course)

1. First select which 5 of the 9 positions in the output word are going to be vowels. This automatically determines which vowel goes where. Then distribute the 4 consonants among the 4 remaining slots, whichever those are. This gives $\binom 95 4!$ possibilities in total.
2. Take all of the words, $9!$ in total. In each *legal* word we can permute the 5 vowels in $5!-1$ ways to get an *illegal* word, and this produces each illegal word exactly once. So the correct count satisfies $n+(5!-1)n=9!$, or $n=9!/5!$.
3. There are 9 places to put F, then 8 places to put C, then 7 places to put T, then 6 places to put S, and once that is done, there's only one way to place the vowels. Total number of words $9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6$.

Comment: I always enjoy how there are several ways to visualize a problem, each of which arriving at the same answer but with different flavors as in this case.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: Your 3rd way is marvellous.

Comment: Yes, +1 from me for that third solution.

Comment: @TonyK: How do I improve my Combinatorics,Probability and Graph Theory. What are the good resources apart from practicing alot. ?

Comment: @Henning Makholm: How do I improve my Combinatorics,Probability and Graph Theory. What are the good resources apart from practicing alot. ?

Answer (score 2):

It’s actually easier to think of it the other way around. The letters F, C, T, and S will occupy $4$ positions, and they can appear in any of $4!=24$ orders. Their $4$ positions determine $5$ slots for the vowels:

$$_X_X_X_X_$$

Once you know how many of the vowels are in each of those $5$ slots, you know exactly which vowel goes where, since the order of the vowels is fixed. Thus, if $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$, and $x_5$ are the numbers of vowels in the first, second, third, fourth, and fifth slot, respectively, you’re looking for the number of solutions in non-negative integers to the equation

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=5\;.$$

This is a standard [stars and bars problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29); the explanation at the link is fairly decent.

Comment: This looks overly complicated to me!

Comment: @Tony: That depends entirely on what you already know and what you happen to see first. (And it’s certainly simpler than an analysis by cases.)

Comment: @Brian M. Scott :Thanks, your approach is nice one though. May be useful for solving quite a good number of problems.

Comment: @user2016963: You’re welcome. Tony’s is probably the simplest, but I’ve found that with elementary combinatorics it helps to have as many weapons available as possible!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: My solution is no longer the simplest, after Henning Makholm posted his solution no. 3.

Comment: @Tony: *More complicated* is not an absolute notion. In practice it depends a great deal on what one sees first, which in turn depends a great deal on one’s background. I personally consider Henning’s second answer the least accessible, followed by JMoravitz’s answer, and I consider Henning’s third answer almost insignificantly different from yours and his first.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: How do I improve my Combinatorics,Probability and Graph Theory. What are the good resources apart from practicing alot. ?

Comment: @user2016963: Are you using a textbook now, and if so, what?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: "more complicated" is indeed a subjective notion. Which is why I wrote "This looks overly complicated to me". But I suspect that in this case everybody except you would agree that your answer is more complicated than Henning's third answer. (I apologise if you are replying to my deleted comment $-$ I deleted it when I saw your second comment, which seemed be in agreement with mine.)

Comment: @Brian: The difference is that my third approach doesn't have a binomial coefficient in it, but the first one does. $\binom ab$ is arguably the least intuitive basic counting formula in elementary combinatorics (compared to $a^b$ and $a!$), so some readers might prefer seeing it sidestepped.

Comment: @Henning: When I taught the subject at an elementary level, I *defined* $\binom{n}k$ to be the number of different $k$-subsets of an $n$-set; in that approach it becomes a fundamental concept, though of course one still has to figure out how to compute it.

Comment: @Brian: Agree that the _concept_ is simple enough. It's the _computation_ thereof that I call less intuitive.

Comment: @Henning: I can agree with that, but it seems to me that it’s the concept that matters most when one is trying to figure out how to analyze one of these problems.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I am using rosen, but many of the concepts are not explained in detail, like the 4 of the "twelvefold ways", only definition is given. not much details on how and why we have such stirling and partitioning theorems. And also partitioning is not explained properly with illustrations. So i was looking for something, where I could get Explanations and proofs with illustrations of concepts used. And yes Probability I dont have any reference so far. Looking for a good illustrative one with proofs.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all "words" must use *all* letters and that vowels don't necessarily have to be spread out (I.e. examples would be FACETIOUS, CATSEIOUF, AEIOTSFCU, etc...)

For the time being, think of all of the vowels as a single symbol, say, $\heartsuit$.  We are asked how many ways we can rearrange $\heartsuit\heartsuit\heartsuit\heartsuit\heartsuit CFST$.

By the multinomial coefficients thereom, this is $\binom{9}{5,1,1,1,1} = \frac{9!}{5!1!1!1!1!} = \frac{9!}{5!} = 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6$

Now, replace the $\heartsuit$ symbols with the vowels AEIOU in that specific order, not changing the total.

Comment: This agrees with my answer $\binom{9}{5}4!$

Comment: @JMoravitz: Thanks alot for the solution, How do I improve my Combinatorics,Probability and Graph Theory. What are the good resources apart from practicing alot. ?